# Ubuntu 13.10 on SSD (system) and HDD (data). Missing /grub/i386-pc/normal.mod

Tags: installation, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I've got a HDD (750 GB) and a SSD (16 GB). I want to install Ubuntu (13.10) on the SSD, but because of its small size, I need to install /home, /var and /tmp on the HDD. After that, I would like to install Windows (system + data) on another partition of that HDD, but it is not important now.

I installed Ubuntu (I had formatted and partitioned the disk before), but when I restarted my laptop it said:

```
'error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
 grub rescue>'
```

I tried to reinstall Grub 2 using [this](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.Um7TLHigphE) tutorial (as sdXY I used sdb1, because it's the only one partition of my SSD), but it didn't work.

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it myself (I'm writing from my another account). I tried Boot Repair, but it didn't work either (thank you for tip anyway, Novine). I'm not sure what exactly solved the problem, but it might be the EFI partition which I have been forgetting to create when I have been trying before.
thank you for your help,
Tatarkow

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from a Live USB and using [Boot Repair](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/)